# WP_Query doesn't order by price meta value

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this wp_query $args to get products from woocommerce querying them by some $_GET parameters I used for filters. 
Actually my problem is that sorting by price isn't working at all. I used this kind of attributes many times but actually here isn't working.
I paste here my code.

```
if ($_GET['filter_pietre'] != -1 && $_GET['filter_pietre'] != NULL) {
    $pietre_operator = 'IN';
} else {
    $pietre_operator = 'NOT IN';
}
if ($_GET['filter_metals'] != -1 && $_GET['filter_metals'] != NULL) {
    $metals_operator = 'IN';
} else {
    $metals_operator = 'NOT IN';
}
if ($_GET['filter_finitura'] != -1 && $_GET['filter_finitura'] != NULL) {
    $finishes_operator = 'IN';
} else {
    $finishes_operator = 'NOT IN';
}
if ($_GET['filter_coloresmalto'] != -1 && $_GET['filter_coloresmalto'] != NULL) {
    $pa_coloresmalto = 'IN';
} else {
    $pa_coloresmalto = 'NOT IN';
}
if ($_GET['filter_ispirazione'] != -1 && $_GET['filter_ispirazione'] != NULL) {
    $pa_ispirazione = 'IN';
} else {
    $pa_ispirazione = 'NOT IN';
}
$params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            //filters
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',    
                'value' => 'instock'
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key' => '_price',
                'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $term_id
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_pietre',
                'terms' => $_GET['filter_pietre'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => $pietre_operator
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_metals',
                'terms' => $_GET['filter_metals'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => $metals_operator
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_finishes',
                'terms' => $_GET['filter_finitura'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => $finishes_operator
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_coloresmalto',
                'terms' => $_GET['filter_coloresmalto'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => $pa_coloresmalto
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_ispirazione',
                'terms' => $_GET['filter_ispirazione'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => $pa_ispirazione
            )
        ),
    );
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
```

Actually sorting by any other attributes works properly but not price.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not place those $_GET variables within your query!

Comment: I solved, meta informations position was wrong. Now I post the solution. Any suggestions to improve my solution is accepted

Comment: @BasvanDijk Problem is not $_GET varables. Query works properly. It was about meta price order position

Comment: I don't mean that it doesn't work. But you should not use variables directly inside of a query.

Comment: @BasvanDijk oh got it. Why ? It can create problems ? I use them to filter products. I previously did by post but it create problems for SEO

Comment: Are you using this in the frontend. Where no login credentials are needed?

Comment: @BasvanDijk yes it's used on frontend with no login credentials needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some modification in your arguments. Please use below one.

```
   $params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => '_price',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'meta_query' => array(
        //filters
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',    
            'value' => 'instock'
        )

    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $term_id
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_pietre',
            'terms' => $_GET['filter_pietre'],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => $pietre_operator
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_metals',
            'terms' => $_GET['filter_metals'],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => $metals_operator
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_finishes',
            'terms' => $_GET['filter_finitura'],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => $finishes_operator
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_coloresmalto',
            'terms' => $_GET['filter_coloresmalto'],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => $pa_coloresmalto
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_ispirazione',
            'terms' => $_GET['filter_ispirazione'],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => $pa_ispirazione
        )
    ),
);
 $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
```

You have added the order by in meta query that should be in outside.

Comment: Exaclty ! I delete my solution below. It's exactly the same.